# How to implement Native ads through Manual Integration in android using MOPUB

Tags: android, ads, mopub

Trying to integrate Mopub native ads into android app.

i have successfully integrated banner and interstitial ads from mopub but struggling with native ads.

Native Ad is Loaded into `onNativeLoad()`, but need help with attaching the native ad view to the Mainactivity view

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private MoPubView moPubView;
//private MoPubInterstitial mInterstitial;
private MoPubNative moPubNative;
private MoPubNativeNetworkListener moPubNativeNetworkListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    moPubNativeNetworkListener = new MoPubNativeNetworkListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeLoad(NativeAd nativeAd) {

            Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad has loaded.");



        }

        @Override
        public void onNativeFail(NativeErrorCode errorCode) {
            Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad failed to load with error: " + errorCode.toString());
        }
    };

    moPubNative = new MoPubNative(this, "11a17b188668469fb0412708c3d16813 ", moPubNativeNetworkListener);

    ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_ad_list_item)
            .mainImageId(R.id.native_main_image)
            .iconImageId(R.id.native_icon_image)
            .titleId(R.id.native_title)
            .textId(R.id.native_text)
            .privacyInformationIconImageId(R.id.native_privacy_information_icon_image)
            .build();


    MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer = new MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(viewBinder);
    moPubNative.registerAdRenderer(moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer);


    EnumSet<RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset> desiredAssets = EnumSet.of(
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.TITLE,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.TEXT,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.CALL_TO_ACTION_TEXT,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.MAIN_IMAGE,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.ICON_IMAGE,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.STAR_RATING
    );

    RequestParameters mRequestParameters = new RequestParameters.Builder()
            .desiredAssets(desiredAssets)
            .build();

    moPubNative.makeRequest();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When `onNativeLoad()` fires with an instance of `NativeAd`, you need to get the pre-rendered ad view from MoPub, then add it to a parent view in your view hierarchy:

```
final View adView = adapterHelper.getAdView(null, nativeAdView, nativeAd, new ViewBinder.Builder(0).build());

adView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
parentView.addView(adView);
```

- `nativeAdView`: your Android layout to house the ad view.
- `nativeAd`: your native ad instance provided from the `onNativeLoad()` callback.
- `parentView`: your Android layout to hold the `nativeAdView`.

Answer (score 0):

created the `ad_holder` in the `actvity_main.xml`.

The `nativead` view is passed to that `ad_holder`.

is it an right approach to do, if not comment below.

```
RelativeLayout adParent = findViewById(R.id.ad_holder);
            View adView = nativeAd.createAdView(getBaseContext(), adParent);
            nativeAd.prepare(adView);
            nativeAd.renderAdView(adView);
            adParent.addView(adView);
```